# Vader Sentiment values not coming out correctly

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I'm using vader sentiment to analyze CSV files full of tweets. I'm try to get an average for each of the sentiment values for the entire set of Tweets. For some reason, many of the results tend to come out with values of 0 which doesn't make sense unless it's a rounding issue. Also len(result[i]) always returns 1. My code is as follows:

```
for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
    result = { 'pos':[] , 'neg':[], 'compound':[], 'neu':[] }
    sentences = row
    f = open(file_name[0], 'a', newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for sentence in sentences:
        vs = vaderSentiment(sentence)
        row = [sentence, str(vs)]
        writer.writerow(row)
        result['pos'].append(vs['pos'])
        result['neg'].append(vs['neg'])
        result['compound'].append(vs['compound'])
        result['neu'].append(vs['neu'])
print('sum:')
for i in result.keys():
    print('\t',i, '=>', float(sum(result[i]))/len(result[i]))
f.close()
```

Comment: How very nice that people choose to downvote and offer no help or explanation for doing so.

Comment: You didn't provide your input data, or what you expected as output. Nor where you got that  `vaderSentiment` function.

Comment: Thanks, that's fair. I've had my face buried in this stuff quite a bit lately so I  forgot it might be vague for some people. Vader Sentiment is a popular sentiment analysis package in Python. It's quite interesting but there's very little documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I realized I was stupidly placing result = { 'pos':[] , 'neg':[], 'compound':[], 'neu':[] } where I shouldn't have so it was clearing the data at each iteration of the loop. I can't believe that took me so long to figure out...